# Translate SELECT DISTINCT t-sql query to DAX expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerbi, dax

I need to create calculate table for the report in PowerBI Desktop. 
I  know how to do that in t-sql but I am unable to interpret it to DAX. 
So should I use t-sql and add this query  using "Get Data"?
Or should I create calculate table using DAX?
Which one is more efficient?

```
select distinct PolicyNumber,
        ReserveStatus, 
        case when ReserveStatus = 'Open' then 1 else 0 end as OpenStatus 
from RockhillClaimsDataFeed_PBI
group by PolicyNumber,ReserveStatus
```

Result looks like that:

[image]

can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is achievable by creating a calculated table in Power BI, with similar syntax using [SELECTCOLUMNS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt761759.aspx) and `DISTINCT`.

```
RockhillClaimsSummary = 
DISTINCT(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        RockhillClaims,
        "PolicyNumber", RockhillClaims[PolicyNumber],
        "ReserveStatus", RockhillClaims[ReserveStatus],
        "OpenStatus", IF(RockhillClaims[ReserveStatus] = "Open", 1, 0)
    )
)
```

Results:

[image: results]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I am going through learning basic DAX queries. Pretty interesting.

Comment: @Oleg I'm sure you can pick it up easily with a SQL background :) Though they do require a different thinking process if you want to get the best out of DAX / Power BI.